# using ajax to query sql

Tags: ajax

i tried to adapt this tutorial:

https://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/dynamically-load-mysql-data-using-jquery-and-php/

for my plugin. When i didn't work i read that for wordpress you have use `jQuery` instead of `$` and enqueue the script with `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');`
so i tried the following code in my main php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'mein-plugin', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mein-plugin' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
}



function sqlTest() {


    return '<input type="text" id="inp" name="inp"/></span>
            <div class="results"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function(){

                    jQuery(\'#inp\').keyup(function(){
                        var inpval= jQuery(\'#inp\').val();
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: \'POST\',  
                            data: ({p : inpval}),
                            url: \'sql.php\',
                            success: function(data) {
                                 jQuery(\'.results\').html(data); 
                         });
                    });

                });
            </script>';
}

add_shortcode("sql", "sqlTest");
```

and my sql.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['p'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row['user_login'];
}

?>
```

(I know that currently the query is independent from the user-input)
Now, [sql] produces an input field, but when i enter something, nothing happens.
What am i doing wrong?

Sorry i'm new to wordpress, jquery and ajax

Comment: Also in your console are you seeing errors. My biggest problem is you are building a javascript function outside of DOM, that can be a dire issue. You may want to try using $(window).on('keyup','#inp',function(){

Comment: I would be deeply suspicious of that tutorial, the end result is a major security problem. If you need to make a request to WP, don't use a standalone file, use a REST API endpoint. Also look at the code and the variable names in your `sql.php`, nowhere do you connect to the server, and you use variables that don't exist

Answer (score 0):

[See documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

WordPress have admin-ajax.php file in wp-includes/ folder. Put in your data parametr `action` and create hooks:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_{your_action}', 'handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_{your_action}', 'handler');
```

ajax.url parametr you can get by using `wp_localize_script('YOUR SCRIPT handle', 'ajax', array('url'=> admin_url('admin-ajax.php')))`

All code must looks like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts' );
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'mein-plugin', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mein-plugin' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-sender', plugins_url( 'ajax-sender.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-sender', 'ajax', array(
        'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'my_nonce' ),
    ) );
}
```

Javascript file:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#inp').keyup(function () {
        var inpval = jQuery('#inp').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'simple_wordpress_ajax',
                nonce: ajax.my_nonce,
                p: inpval
            },
            url: ajax.url,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('.results').html(data.html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_simple_wordpress_ajax', 'simple_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_simple_wordpress_ajax', 'simple_ajax_handler');

function simple-wordpress-ajax(){
    check_ajax_referer('my_nonce', 'nonce', true);
    // your php code

    $return = array('html' => 'test'); // your data for return
    wp_send_json_success($return);
}
```

Something like this.